# Why do Javascript exceptions leave the interpreter in an unpredictable state?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Exceptions cause Node.js servers to crash. The common wisdom is that one needs to monitor Node.js processes and restart them on crash.  Why can't one just wrap the entire script in a  `try {} catch {}` or listen for exception events?

It's understood that catching all exceptions is bad because it leaves the interpreter in an unpredictable state. Is this actually true? Why? Is this an issue specific to V8?

Comment: Wrapping the entire script won't work due to callbacks. E.g. `try{ setTimeout(function() { throw new Error; }, 100); } catch(e) {}` will still raise the error because the `try catch` only takes account for the actual `setTimeout` call and not what happens in the callback.

Comment: @pimvdb Ah, good point. And Node.js uses setTimeout profusely, so this is likely to be an important issue on a regular vanilla Node.js app, right?

Comment: As far as I know `setTimeout` is not extremely common in Node, but of course most of the IO functions do accept callbacks. But they all pass the error along (as first callback argument, or use `.on("error"` for `EventEmitter`s), so you should be able to catch most errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catching all exception does not leave the interpreter in a bad state, but may leave your application in a bad state. An uncaught exception means that something that you were expecting to work, failed, and your application does not know how to handle that failure.

For example, if your app is a web server that listens to port 80 for connections, and when the app launches the port is in use, an exception is raised. Your code may ignore it, and then the process may continue running without actually listening to the port, so the process will be futile, or handle it: print an error message, a warning, kill the other process, or any way you want it to be handled. But you can see why ignoring it is not a good idea.

Another example is failing to communicate with a database (dropping a connection, unable to connect, receiving an unexpected error). If you app flow does not catch the exception properly, but just ignores it, you may be sending the user an acknowledgement of an event that failed.

Comment: That is true I just assumed he was talking about the application. Did not catch the interpreter part.

Answer (score -1):

Exceptions are part of the event engine. Instead of wrapping in a try what you want to do is listen for that exception
http://debuggable.com/posts/node-js-dealing-with-uncaught-exceptions:4c933d54-1428-443c-928d-4e1ecbdd56cb 
 Then respond in the proper manner.

As for the second part of your question:

It really depends on your application. You need to test to see if the exception is something more or less you expect. Sometimes an exception is real not just a file not found.

Comment: Catching exceptions using events is just an implementation detail, but I've edited my answer per your suggestion. I'm not sure this is an answer to my core question. Fundamentally, exceptions are exceptional, one can't expect to exhaustively test all possible scenarios. I'm looking for an understanding of the fundamentals of exception handling in Javascript.

Comment: I don`t think that they are different then exception handling in any other system. Catching a catastrophic exception is a good time to log it alert you and restart itself if possible. I do think you can not test them all but there may be ones that you well expect.